# Are people on average more likely to die in an extinction event than in a car crash?

Tags: extinction-event

[An article in The Atlantic](http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2016/04/a-human-extinction-isnt-that-unlikely/480444/) makes following claim:

> **Human Extinction Isn't That Unlikely**
>
> “A typical person is more than five times as likely to die in an extinction event as in a car crash,” says a new report

This is all based on assuming that there is annualized 0.1% chance of a global extinction event. However that number seems to be just trumped up.

Is there any hard scientific evidence for these estimates?

Comment: Answer that would explain why the two measures are not comparable would be fine too.

Comment: @vartec Are they counting natural extinction events only or anthropogenic as well?

Comment: @Dawn Good point, answers should also take into account that location is a variable: space impactors are likely to affect certain areas more strongly and climate change affects coastal areas more than inland.

Comment: Atlantic: "Every year, one in 9,395 people die in a crash." [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=population+of+world+%2F++car+crash+deaths+per+year): 5614 people per death (2013 estimate)

Comment: @called2voyage: I think that answers should match what the claimant (e.g. the Stern Report) intended, explaining what that is, if necessary.

Comment: @Oddthinking Actually the Atlantic is concerned with Global Challenges Foundation’s report, not the earlier Stern Review. But yes, we should focus on what is in that report. Apparently, they are including all events anthropogenic and natural. Though the 0.1 percent figure does come from the Stern Review.

Comment: @Oddthinking yeah, they're mixing up “people” with “Americans” in few places.

Comment: What I have figured so far: The Atlantic relied on the [Global Challenges Foundation report](http://globalprioritiesproject.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Global-Catastrophic-Risk-Annual-Report-2016-FINAL.pdf) which is about risks to at least 10% of the population. On Page 24, it cites the [Stern Review](http://web.archive.org/web/20081211182219/http://www.hm-treasury.gov.uk/stern_review_final_report.htm) which is apparently about species extinction events, and has the figures the Atlantic have quoted.

Comment: Given that it's been millions of years since the last global extinction event, an average of 1 global extinction every 1000 years seems, uh, high.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - given that it's been millions of years since the last global extinction event it seems reasonable to assume we're due. Get out those tinfoil meteor-repelling hats, folks, we're in for a bumpy ride..! :-) (Interestingly, yesterday I was reading about the Burckle crater, an undersea feature in the Indian ocean which is hypothesized to be a meteor impact crater from circa 5000 years ago which could be the source of "flood" events in world religions. Given that an ocean impact would have caused devastating climatological consequences I am a bit skeptical, but... :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis You've just committed the [Gambler's fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler's_fallacy). If you flip a coin 10 times and get 10 heads, you still have a 50/50 chance of getting tails the next flip. The idea that we're "due" assumes a causal link between extinction events, or that by not having one we're "building up".

Comment: @Schwern: I think Bob was joking, but it's not implausible that there might be a causal link between extinction events, or "building up" (e.g. several-million-year-period galactic orbital mechanics bringing us together with rogue objects; some sort of accretion process in the core; who knows.)

Comment: ?!? You don't die of extinction. Claim needs context.

Comment: @Schwern - I don't think that's a fallacy.  If I give you a coin that may not be fair and you flip it 10 times and get 10 heads, it's probably not fair.  Same thing here.  But actually more extreme.  If it were really 0.1% chance, the probability of making it 10000 years would be about 5x10^{-5}.  But we're talking about managing that 100 times - we're talking about a number that is around 10^{-500}.  What's more likely - that we're in that scenario, or that the 0.1% number was incorrectly arrived at?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft We only developed the atomic bomb 70 years ago and already had a few near-misses. Biological weapons or the singularity (AI becoming more intelligent than humans) pose another significant danger. So I don't think you can use the past million years to estimate the chance of a mass extinction. Personally I think the chance is significantly higher than 0.1% per year, at least if you count events that "only" kill a large fraction of humans and not all of them. For example an all out nuclear war between the US and the SU did not seem *that* unlikely during the cold war.

Comment: Those who think it's highly probable that we die of extinction should notice that this is a believe that can be found throughout the history of mankind, yet never happened. Please be careful when you drive.

Comment: Hard scientific evidence doesn't deal with probabilities.

Comment: The title should probably be changed to "die in a global extinction event". It doesn't make sense to say "die from extinction". Extinction is not the cause of death. Rather "Extinction"  is caused by the cumulative effect of the deaths, or specifically the last death that makes the species extinct.

Comment: It seems awfully strange to try to estimate the probability of events that would render economics pointless. Why try to do that? It is like trying to estimate the likelihood of your chess game ending because of terrorists. It is not in scope. If you think the economic system could collapse, you should be departing the scene as quickly as possible, not figuring what your losses might be. Everything! *Run Away!*

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft: But the Earth is experiencing a major extinction event right now (right now defined as a process playing out over several centuries or so).  The question might be re-worded as the probability that humans will be numbered among the extinct species when the event reaches its conclusion.

Comment: What if the extinction is caused by car crashes?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

**Summary.** There's no factual basis to the claim that there is a 0.1% annual risk of human extinction. What happened is that this figure was used by the authors of the [Stern Review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern_Review) as a *conservative assumption* in their calculation of a [discount rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economics_of_climate_change_mitigation#Discount_rates) for future costs and benefits, but a [game of whispers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers) has caused this context to be lost.

**Details.** Let's chase down the references and see where this came from, starting with the source given in the OP:

1. Robinson Meyer (2016). "[Human Extinction Isn't That Unlikely](http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2016/04/a-human-extinction-isnt-that-unlikely/480444/)". *The Atlantic*.

   > The Stern Review, the U.K. government’s premier report on the economics of climate change, assumed a 0.1-percent risk of human extinction every year.

   It looks as if Meyer based this sentence on:
2. Cotton-Barratt et al. (2016). "[Global Catastrophic Risks](http://globalprioritiesproject.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Global-Catastrophic-Risk-Annual-Report-2016-FINAL.pdf)". The Global Priorities Project.

   > The UK’s Stern Review on the Economics of Climate Change suggested a 0.1% chance of human extinction each year.

   Notice that this is not quite the same as the claim in Meyer. Meyer wrote "assumed" but this only says "suggested".

   Cotton-Barratt et al. cite this claim to:
3. Nick Bostrom (2013). "[Existential Risk Prevention as Global Priority](http://www.existential-risk.org/concept.pdf)". *Global Policy* 4:1 15–31.

   > The UK’s influential Stern Review on the Economics of Climate Change (2006) used an extinction probability of 0.1 per cent per year in calculating an effective discount rate.

   Note that, again, this is quite not the same as the claim in Cotton-Barratt et al. Bostrom says that the Stern review "used an extinction probability ... in calculating an effective discount rate". Using a probability in a technical calculation is not the same as suggesting its truth.

   Bostrom cites this to:
4. Nicholas Stern (2006). "[Stern review on the economics of climate change](http://webarchive.nationalarchives.gov.uk/20081230223646/http://www.hm-treasury.gov.uk/d/Chapter_2_Technical_Annex.pdf)". H.M. Treasury.

   Section 2A.2 is a technical discussion of "Intertemporal appraisals and discounting". The problem under discussion is how to compare costs and benefits across long periods of time:

   > Different strategies for climate change will yield different patterns of consumption over time. We assume that a choice between strategies will depend on their consequences for households now and in the future.

   The approach taken is to use a "[discount rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economics_of_climate_change_mitigation#Discount_rates)" — costs and benefits are accorded lower utility the further they are in the future. The discount rate takes into account various forms of uncertainty about the future, and one of these factors is:

   > uncertainty about existence of future generations arising from some possible shock which is exogenous to the issues and choices under examination (we used the metaphor of the meteorite).

   Some illustrative figures are drawn up (see table 2A.1) to show the effect of various values for the extinction rate δ, and it is at this point that the authors write:

   > For δ=0.1 per cent there is an almost 10% chance of extinction by the end of a century. That itself seems high – indeed if this were true, and had been true in the past, it would be remarkable that the human race had lasted this long.

   It's clear that this figure is just plucked out of the air: no basis is given for it. It's not a serious attempt to estimate the risk of extinction. The point is that unless δ is really high (much bigger than 0.1%) it is dominated by the other contributions to the discount rate in the model (namely elasticity of marginal utility and growth rate) and so the Stern Review's conclusions don't depend on its exact value, and so there is no need for them to make a serious estimation.

**Update.** After the problems with the *Atlantic* article (see [this article by nostalgebraist](http://nostalgebraist.tumblr.com/post/143718406034/the-future-of-humanity-institute-seems-very)) were brought to their attention, the Global Priorities Project issued an [erratum](http://globalprioritiesproject.org/2016/05/errata-to-global-catastrophic-risks-2016/):

> We were aware that the Stern Review used this figure merely as a modelling assumption, and were trying to give a concise accurate statement. Our intention in using the figure from the Stern Review was not to try to pin down an accurate estimate of the likelihood of global catastrophe, but to demonstrate that existing serious analysis treats the 0.1% probability as a plausible modeling assumption, which would have consequences that are interesting and non-intuitive. [...]
>
> The car crash comparison was picked up in *The Atlantic*, which reported it as an unconditional claim and emphasised it in their article. We did not intend to argue that the 0.1% figure was an accurate estimate of extinction risk (as we did not plan to offer an estimate of extinction risk), so this was inadvertently misleading to *Atlantic* readers.

Comment: +1 for tracing so many steps! Joined this particular SE site just to upvote this :)

Comment: +1 But reading the full paragraph in the Global Catastrophic Risks 2016 publication I have to say the fault really lies with the Atlantic article. I mean, sure, the GCR 2016 publication could have made it far more clearer that they were just giving a math lesson and the final editing work such as the pull quotes were unfortunate, but reading through the article itself (rather than the unfortunate pull quote summary) didn't imply anything close to the Atlantic article. The way you presented it is as if the only mistake the Atlantic made was switching the word 'suggested' with 'assumed'.

Comment: @DavidMulder: In this answer I only looked at the "0.1%" claim. (You'll see that there was plenty there for one answer!) If you want to write another answer about some of the other claims in the *Atlantic* article, that would be great.

Comment: That 'correction' still shows a fundamental misunderstanding of the point of the statistic; namely that it is an unrealistic upper bound used to show the irrelevance of the event to the analysis in question.  It's like me saying even if there was a 50% of dying from skydiving I would still do it; I'm not saying 50% is an accurate number, I'm saying that I really want to skydive and no reasonable estimate on the probability of a catastrophic outcome would dissuade me.

Comment: Echoes of: http://www.internetjournalofcriminology.com/Sutton_Spinach_Iron_and_Popeye_March_2010.pdf

Comment: "For δ=0.1 per cent there is an almost 10% chance of extinction by the end of a century. That itself seems high – indeed if this were true, and had been true in the past, it would be remarkable that the human race had lasted this long."

You can't really use use the data from before nuclear weapons, biological warfare, climate change and industrial scale farming to conclude anything about the present chances of survival. Of course we didn't wipe ourselves out in 1342, how could we have?

Comment: @Scott A mass extinction event doesn't have to be man-made, and the black plague from almost exactly the time period you refer (14th century AD), is arguably the closest human's have come a mass extinction event at least since that time and it didn't require nuclear weapons.  Advances in technology ave both increased *and* decreased the likelihood of a mass human extinction event.

Comment: And the point about the 0.1% is that in itself, it is already an extraordinarily high number.  Even if we assume Stern didn't agree with your assessment of the current likelihood, it's still probably much lower than 0.1%.  But the *larger* point here is that Stern isn't even trying to make an accurate assessment of the likelihood.  He's actually trying to purposefully overestimate it for the purposes of demonstrating that it is unlikely enough to not be statistically relevant for whatever work he is actually doing.

Comment: Perhaps most importantly here, Stern is an economist.  He's not really particularly in a field suited for studying mass extinction events (and therefore putting numbers on the likelihood of any future mass extinction events).

Comment: @ nhgrif - how would the black plague have killed the Aboriginal people in Australia? Or the Maoris in New Zealand?

Answer (score -4):

It depends what you mena by "hard scientific evidence". If you mean empirical evidence that has been verified in the field and can be reliably reproduced in the lab. Then the answer is no, it is impossible to gather "hard scientific evidence" about the extinction of our species because we would need to, as extinct persons, observe the extinction of our species to gather this evidence

Here is a quote from a relevant text (http://www.globalchallenges.org/reports/Global-Catastrophic-Risk-Annual-Report-2016.pdf)

*When dealing with global
catastrophic risks we cannot
generally rely on historical
experience or trial and error.
Given the severity of global catastrophes,
learning from experience would
be extremely costly or, in the event
of human extinction, impossible.*